# Wait excel to hide graph using vba

Tags: excel, vba

when i try this step by step in debug mode it works fine

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
For Each Graph In Sheets("alex").ChartObjects
    Graph.Visible = False
Next
Sheets("alex").Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Sheets("alex").Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

But when i run this, graphs are not hidden as it seems that when

```
Sheets("alex").Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

is called, excel has not hide the graph yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried your code, without the debug mode & it work fine on my side.  I hope you find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a do events line in:
 grapth.visible = false 
Do events
Next

Comment: I tried that, visible property is false but graph is not not visible yet. Its like excel starts making graph invisible in a new thread while next line is called before this thread have finished.